# How do I create a spiral off-shoot from my larger spiral?

Tags: python, fractals

I'm coding in python. I've created a spiral with my current for loop below. I want to create tiny spiral off-shoots around every 10 degrees. The problem is I don't know how to do that. I'm trying to do something like this:

[image: fractal image]

My question is how would I create the off-shoots? Is this even possible or not?
Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

```
import turtle
import math
me = turtle.Turtle()


def miniSpiral():
    for i in range(0,360):
        x,y = me.position()
        me.left(1)
        if x%10==0:
            x2,y2 = me.forward(((5*i)+5)*math.pi/360)
        else:
            x2,y2= me.forward(5*math.pi/360)
        me.goto((x+x2),(y+y2))

for x2 in range(0,720):
    me.left(1)
    if x2%10==0:
        me.forward(((10*x2)+10)*math.pi/360)
        #miniSpiral()
    me.forward(10*math.pi/360)
```

Comment: I'm confused by your code. When I use the `turtle` library on either of Python 2.7 or 3.5, I don't get any return value from the `forward` method on a `Turtle` object. You also are passing it a value that looks like it is intended to be an angle, rather than a distance. Are you using a non-standard `turtle` module?

Comment: It's actually occurred to me that using `pi` in a distance might be appropriate when you're measuring along the circumference of an arc or circle, so that part of my comment may not be valid.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the easiest way to draw a fractal programmatically is to use recursion. Start with the code to draw one "segment" of your fractal. In the image you linked to, that would be one 90-degree piece of the spiral (since that's the distance between the branchings).

Once you have code that can draw one segment, you add a recursive call to it. Give it some parameter (e.g. the initial size), and have the recursive call reduce the value passed on to the next call. Add a base case where a call with that parameter set too small gets skipped (e.g. `if size < 1: return`) so that the recursion doesn't go on forever.

Now you can add branching. Instead of just one recursive call, make two. You'll need to add some extra logic to move the position of the turtle in between the calls (so the second one starts at roughly the same spot as the first), but that shouldn't be too hard. To make the two branches distinct, vary their initial position or angle, or give them different parameters. In your example image, the "extra" branches all start going the oposite direction from the "main" branch, and they start smaller.

Here's a pseudo-code implementation of the spiral you want (I'm not adding actual `turtle` code because you seem to be using a different `turtle` module than the one I have from the standard library):

```
def spiral(size):
    if size < 1: return # base case
    draw_segment(size) # this draws a 90 degree piece of the spiral

    position = getposition() # save state so we can back up after the first recursive call
    angle = getangle()

    spiral(size - 1) # main branch of the recursion

    penup()  # restore state (mostly)
    setposition(position)
    pendown()
    setangle(angle + 180) # we want to start facing the other direction for the second branch

    spiral(size - 2) # extra branch of the recursion
```

You can play around with the details (like how you modify the `size` for the recursive calls) to suit your tastes or the fractal design you're looking for. For instance, you could multiply the size by some factor (e.g. `size * 0.75`) rather than subtracting a fixed amount.

Answer (score 0):

Each mini spiral is just a smaller version of the original spiral, as such you can carefully call the original function to make each smaller one.

```
import turtle
import math


def spiral(steps, left, forward, level):
    for step in range(50, steps):
        me.left(left)
        me.forward(step / forward)

        if step % 200 == 0 and level > 0:
            x, y = me.position()
            heading = me.heading()
            spiral((steps * 2) / 3, -left * 1.2, forward * 1.2, level - 1)
            me.up()
            me.setpos(x, y)
            me.setheading(heading)
            me.down()

#turtle.tracer(5, 200)     # to speed things up
me = turtle.Turtle()
spiral(800, 0.6, 200.0, 4)
```

Each time `spiral()` is called, the arguments are modified slightly and the level is reduced by `1`. Also the `left` argument is made negative which has the effect of changing the direction for each sub spiral. Each sub spiral is called after `200` steps. Each sub spiral has 2/3rds of the original steps and so on.... lots of numbers to play with to see how they effect the outcome. When the sub spiral finishes drawing, it jumps back to the point where it started drawing it an continues with the original spiral.

Calling it with a level of `0` would give you a single simple spiral for example.

This would give you the following type of output:

[image: Turtle fractal spiral]